# Redshift Serializable Isolation violation error message transaction ids wrong?

Tags: database, concurrency, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to identify transactions that are violating serializable isolation on Redshift
e.g.

```
ERROR:  1023
DETAIL:  Serializable isolation violation on table - 4117431, transactions forming the cycle are: 246544535, 246540473 (pid:1777)
```

In trying to better understand this, I was playing with the toy example in the AWS docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_serial_isolation.html#c_serial_isolation-serializable-isolation-troubleshooting

The error message seems to be including a transaction id that isn't one of the concurrent transactions I am currently running. Am I misunderstanding something?

I did 2 experiments to confirm this:

**Experiment 1**

Transaction 1 (T1) - user: user_a

```
mydb=> begin;
BEGIN
mydb=*> select * from test.sl;
 id
----
  1
  3
  7
  2
(4 rows)

mydb=*> insert into test.sl2 values (7);
INSERT 0 1
mydb=*> end;
COMMIT
```

Transaction 2 (T2) - user: user_b

```
mydb=# begin;
BEGIN
mydb=*# select * from test.sl2;
 id
----
 11
  3
  9
  8
(4 rows)

mydb=*# insert into test.sl values (6);
ERROR:  1023
DETAIL:  Serializable isolation violation on table - 4117431, transactions forming the cycle are: 246544535, 246540473 (pid:1777)
mydb=!# end;
```

Debugging

```
mydb=# select xid, 
              pid,
              starttime,
              endtime,
              sequence, 
              case 
                when xid in (select xact_id from stl_tr_conflict) then 1 
                else 0 
              end as aborted, 
              trim(text) as text 
              from svl_statementtext 
              where xid in (246544535, 246540473) order by xid, sequence, starttime;

    xid    |  pid  |         starttime          |          endtime           | sequence | aborted |               text
-----------+-------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------+---------+-----------------------------------
 246540473 | 31342 | 2021-07-26 10:02:35.975449 | 2021-07-26 10:02:35.975451 |        0 |       0 | begin;
 246540473 | 31342 | 2021-07-26 10:02:40.219189 | 2021-07-26 10:02:40.713895 |        0 |       0 | select * from test.sl;
 246540473 | 31342 | 2021-07-26 10:03:02.616113 | 2021-07-26 10:03:02.628287 |        0 |       0 | insert into test.sl2 values (11);
 246540473 | 31342 | 2021-07-26 10:03:32.585407 | 2021-07-26 10:03:33.036425 |        0 |       0 | COMMIT
 246544535 |  1777 | 2021-07-26 10:14:40.687421 | 2021-07-26 10:14:40.687423 |        0 |       1 | begin;
 246544535 |  1777 | 2021-07-26 10:15:46.711658 | 2021-07-26 10:15:46.71843  |        0 |       1 | select * from test.sl2;
 246544535 |  1777 | 2021-07-26 10:16:03.639541 | 2021-07-26 10:16:03.6423   |        0 |       1 | insert into test.sl values (6);
(7 rows)
```

Already, I see that `xid = 246540473` isn't one of the concurrent transactions (T1 or T2).

So I tested it again.

**Experiment 2**

T1 - user: user_a

```
mydb=> begin;
BEGIN
mydb=*> select * from test.sl;
 id
----
  2
  1
  3
  7
(4 rows)

mydb=*> insert into test.sl2 values (12);
INSERT 0 1
mydb=*>
```

T2 - user: user_b

```
mydb=# begin;
BEGIN
mydb=*# select * from test.sl2;
 id
----
  8
  3
  9
 11
  7
(5 rows)

mydb=*# insert into test.sl values (13);
ERROR:  1023
DETAIL:  Serializable isolation violation on table - 4117431, transactions forming the cycle are: 246549376, 246544529 (pid:6733)
mydb=!#
```

This time though, I noted the transaction ids by querying `svv_transactions` and looking for the `txn_owner`, before I ended both transactions.

```
mydb=# select * from svv_transactions where txn_owner in ('user_b', 'user_a') limit 10;
 txn_owner | txn_db  |    xid    | pid  |         txn_start          |    lock_mode    | lockable_object_type | relation | granted
-----------+---------+-----------+------+----------------------------+-----------------+----------------------+----------+---------
 user_a    | mydb    | 246549373 | 6727 | 2021-07-26 10:46:20.116482 | AccessShareLock | relation             |   252024 | t
 user_a    | mydb    | 246549373 | 6727 | 2021-07-26 10:46:20.116482 | AccessShareLock | relation             |  4117431 | t
 user_a    | mydb    | 246549373 | 6727 | 2021-07-26 10:46:20.116482 | ExclusiveLock   | transactionid        |          | t
 user_b    | mydb    | 246549376 | 6733 | 2021-07-26 10:46:23.702597 | AccessShareLock | relation             |   252024 | t
 user_b    | mydb    | 246549376 | 6733 | 2021-07-26 10:46:23.702597 | AccessShareLock | relation             |  4117498 | t
 user_b    | mydb    | 246549376 | 6733 | 2021-07-26 10:46:23.702597 | ExclusiveLock   | transactionid        |          | t
```

I see that the transaction ids in experiment 2 are `246549373` and `246549376`.
The error message is providing me with `246549376`, which makes sense.
But the second id `246544529`, does not. -- that was from Experiment 1.

```
mydb=# select xid, 
              pid, 
              starttime, 
              endtime, 
              sequence, 
              case 
                when xid in (select xact_id from stl_tr_conflict) then 1 
                else 0 
              end as aborted, 
              trim(text) as text 
              from svl_statementtext 
              where xid in (246549376, 246544529, 246549373) 
              order by xid, starttime, sequence;
    xid    | pid  |         starttime          |          endtime           | sequence | aborted |               text
-----------+------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------+---------+-----------------------------------
 246544529 | 1779 | 2021-07-26 10:14:37.052255 | 2021-07-26 10:14:37.052257 |        0 |       0 | begin;
 246544529 | 1779 | 2021-07-26 10:15:43.173474 | 2021-07-26 10:15:43.185421 |        0 |       0 | select * from test.sl;
 246544529 | 1779 | 2021-07-26 10:15:56.973818 | 2021-07-26 10:15:56.986552 |        0 |       0 | insert into test.sl2 values (7);
 246544529 | 1779 | 2021-07-26 10:16:42.137115 | 2021-07-26 10:16:42.674209 |        0 |       0 | COMMIT
 246549373 | 6727 | 2021-07-26 10:44:37.179593 | 2021-07-26 10:44:37.179594 |        0 |       0 | begin;
 246549373 | 6727 | 2021-07-26 10:46:20.119846 | 2021-07-26 10:46:20.352005 |        0 |       0 | select * from test.sl;
 246549373 | 6727 | 2021-07-26 10:47:00.662191 | 2021-07-26 10:47:00.674989 |        0 |       0 | insert into test.sl2 values (12);
 246549376 | 6733 | 2021-07-26 10:44:38.798094 | 2021-07-26 10:44:38.798095 |        0 |       1 | begin;
 246549376 | 6733 | 2021-07-26 10:46:23.705674 | 2021-07-26 10:46:23.715201 |        0 |       1 | select * from test.sl2;
 246549376 | 6733 | 2021-07-26 10:47:07.167762 | 2021-07-26 10:47:07.17054  |        0 |       1 | insert into test.sl values (13);
(10 rows)
```

Why is it not providing me with `246549373`? What am I not understanding?

References:

- I used this to learn more about the violation: https://medium.com/@salmaan/debugging-redshift-serializable-isolation-violations-16685afdb1d4

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code on a fresh cluster and got what you would expect for transactions in the error message using your debug SQL.  However after rerunning I also get the earlier PID as the being in conflict even though this transaction has been rolled back and has no locks.

Disconnecting the sessions has no effect on this.  Rebooting the cluster doesn't clear this up but does make things weirder - The error message will report only one transaction id!

Looks like you have found a bug in Redshift's error message system and you will want to submit a ticket.  The database is operating properly - detecting and aborting conditions that create circular locks - but the error message generator gets confused when the same tables are in play a second time.  These are rare enough that I expect that they don't have a release test case for multiple serialization errors occurring.

Good catch.

Comment: We reached out to our solutions architect. I'll post updates here.
Thank you for confirming this! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Posting updates is much appreciated.  It looks like you have everything you need for this but if I can help reach out and I'm happy to assist anyway I can.